# Xamarin Android: Cannot convert Java.IO.ByteArrayOutputStream expression to type System.IO.Stream

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android and on line "document.WriteTo(outPut);" I am getting a compile time error. The equivalent code compiles in Java, but using Xamarin and c# I am having some type of casting/conversion issue. Does anyone know how to fix this? What I am trying to do is take my created pdf and turn it into a byte array.

```
 Byte[] MakePDFFromImages(){
        // open a new document
        PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
            SetColorMode(Android.Print.PrintColorMode.Color).
            SetMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.IsoA4).
            SetResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("zooey","test", 450, 700)).
            SetMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NoMargins).
            Build();

        PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument (Activity.BaseContext, printAttributes);

        // start a page
        Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(0);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView (Activity.BaseContext);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap (_imageArray [0]);

        imageView.Draw(page.Canvas);

        document.FinishPage(page);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outPut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            document.WriteTo(outPut);
            document.Close();
            outPut.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception){

        }

        return outPut.ToByteArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintedPdfDocument.Write` expects .NET `Stream`, while you are passing it Java `ByteArrayOutputStream`. To fix, use .NET `MemoryStream`:

```
    Byte[] MakePDFFromImages()
    {
        // open a new document
        PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
            SetColorMode(Android.Print.PrintColorMode.Color).
            SetMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.IsoA4).
            SetResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("zooey", "test", 450, 700)).
            SetMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NoMargins).
            Build();

        PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(Activity.BaseContext, printAttributes);

        // start a page
        Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(0);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Activity.BaseContext);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(_imageArray[0]);

        imageView.Draw(page.Canvas);

        document.FinishPage(page);

        var outPut = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            document.WriteTo(outPut);
            document.Close();
            outPut.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return outPut.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Xamarin API docs, the [WriteTo()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument/) method of [PDFDocument](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument/) expects a .NET System.IO.Stream, not a Java stream.

This [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/App/PrintCustomContent.cs#L473) shows how to use the PDFDocument class in Xamarin